# How to click a button programmatically?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have 2 view controllers which should be swapped according to userinput. So, I want to switch the views programatically based on the input I get from a text file.

```
Algorithm : 
if(input == 1)
{
    Go to View Controller 1
}
else if(input ==2)
{
    Go to View Controller 2 
}
```

Any help on how to click the button programmatically or load that particular viewcontroller with input?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

To fire an event programmatically you need to call `sendActionsForControlEvent`

```
button.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)
```

--

**Swift 3**

```
button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is going to send the action even if you have isUserInteractionEnabled set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just put all the logic that you perform when a button gets clicked in a separate method, and call that method from your button's selector method.

```
@IBAction func someButtonPressed(button: UIButton) {
    pushViewControllerOne()
}

@IBAction func someButtonPressed(button: UIButton) {
    pushViewControllerTwo()
}

func pushViewControllerOne() {
    let viewController = ViewControllerOne(nibName: "ViewControllerOne", bundle: nil)
    pushViewController(viewController)
}

func pushViewControllerTwo() {
    let viewController = ViewControllerOne(nibName: "ViewControllerTwo", bundle: nil)
    pushViewController(viewController)
}

func pushViewController(viewController: UIViewController) {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Then instead of invoking programatically invoking a button press, just call the method `pushViewControllerOne()` or `pushViewControllerTwo()`

Comment: no, that's not what the original poster was asking.

Comment: Well, sometimes one has to read between the lines of what OP wants to achieve. It is often the case where (s)he does not know about a better way of reaching the end goal...

Comment: yes i agree Sajjon, good point, i didn't mean to be so terse, my bad. in this case i think that `button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)` is the right answer, but your solution is also valid.